Are raw sockets affected by iptables rules?
My understanding, from various sources (e.g. here and here) is that raw sockets are not affected by iptables rules. However in practice, I am seeing iptables prevent me from sending packets on a raw socket.
Here are the steps I'm taking to reproduce this (on Debian GNU/Linux 12):

Create main.c with the following content:

#include <errno.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  int ip_sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP);
  if (ip_sock_fd == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create socket: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
  }

  struct sockaddr_in dest_addr = {
      .sin_family = AF_INET,
      .sin_addr =
          (struct in_addr){
              .s_addr = htonl(3232281290)}, // 3232281290 = 192.168.178.202
  };

  if (sendto(ip_sock_fd, "hello", strlen("hello"), 0,
             (struct sockaddr *)(&dest_addr), sizeof(dest_addr)) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to send IP packet: %s\n", strerror(errno));
  };
}



Run gcc main.c && ./a.out (as root). The process completes successfully.

Add an iptables rule to block the outgoing packet: iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -s 192.168.178.202 -j DROP

Try running ./a.out again (still as root). It now fails with Failed to send IP packet: Operation not permitted. So it appears that iptables is affecting the raw socket after all - is that right?



I think my confusion here was due to some ambiguity in the term "raw socket". "Raw socket" can refer to two different types of sockets:

Sockets using PF_INET/AF_INET and SOCK_RAW. Packets on these sockets still pass through the kernel's TCP/IP stack and are processed by iptables/nftables.

Sockets using PF_PACKET/AF_PACKET. Packets on these sockets bypass the kernel's TCP/IP stack entirely and therefore are not affected by iptables/nftables.


This diagram was helpful.
